# Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE

Tags: support, faq, data-explorer, data-dump, schema

Stack Exchange releases "data dumps" of all its publicly available content [roughly every three months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106402/165455) via [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), and also makes that information queryable over the Internet at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) (SEDE) (updated weekly, on Sunday). Over time, as new features and other bits of data are introduced to Stack Exchange sites, the "anatomy" of the data dump is likely to change.

- [What is the current structure of the public data dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678)
- [Is there a diagram of the schema?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326361)

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931)

Answer (score 347):

**About this list:**

- **foreign key** fields are formatted as [links](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) to their parent table
- *italic* table names are found in **both** the Data Dump on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) as well as in the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

---

### *Posts*  / PostsWithDeleted

You find in `Posts` all non-deleted posts. `PostsWithDeleted` includes rows with deleted posts while sharing the same columns with `Posts` but [for deleted posts only a few fields populated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431) which are marked with a <sup>1</sup> below.

- `Id`<sup>1</sup>
- `PostTypeId`<sup>1</sup> *(listed in the [`PostTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)*
  <sub>1 = Question

  2 = Answer

  3 = Orphaned tag wiki

  4 = Tag wiki excerpt

  5 = Tag wiki

  6 = Moderator nomination

  7 = "Wiki placeholder" *(Appears to include auxiliary site content like the [help center introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58551602/body), [election description](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/body), and the tour page's [introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14264003/body), [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14264713/body), and [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14264412/body) sections)*

  8 = Privilege wiki</sub>
- [`AcceptedAnswerId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) *(only present if `PostTypeId = 1`)*
- [`ParentId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts&pk=Id)<sup>1</sup> *(only present if `PostTypeId = 2`)*
- `CreationDate`<sup>1</sup>
- `DeletionDate`<sup>1</sup> *(only non-null for the SEDE `PostsWithDeleted` table. Deleted posts are not present on `Posts`. Column not present on data dump.)*
- `Score`<sup>1</sup> *(generally non-zero for only Questions, Answers, and Moderator Nominations)*
- `ViewCount` *(nullable)*
- `Body` *([as rendered HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51177/include-markdown-post-bodies-in-the-data-dump), not Markdown)*
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(only present if user has not been deleted; always -1 for tag wiki entries, i.e. the community user owns them)*
- `OwnerDisplayName` *(nullable)*
- [`LastEditorUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(nullable)*
- `LastEditorDisplayName` *(nullable)*
- `LastEditDate` (e.g. `2009-03-05T22:28:34.823`) - *the date and time of the most recent edit to the post (nullable)*
- `LastActivityDate` (e.g. `2009-03-11T12:51:01.480`) - *datetime of the post's most recent activity*
- `Title` - *question title (`PostTypeId = 1`), or on Stack Overflow, the tag name for some tag wikis and excerpts (`PostTypeId = 4/5`)*
- `Tags`<sup>1</sup> - *question tags (`PostTypeId = 1`), or on Stack Overflow, the subject tag of some tag wikis and excerpts (`PostTypeId = 4/5`)*
- `AnswerCount` - *the number of undeleted answers (only present if `PostTypeId = 1`)*
- `CommentCount` *(nullable)*
- `FavoriteCount` *(nullable)*
- `ClosedDate`<sup>1</sup> *(present only if the post is closed)*
- `CommunityOwnedDate` *(present only if post is community wiki'd)*
- `ContentLicense`<sup>1</sup>

---

### *Users*

- `Id`
- `Reputation`
- `CreationDate`
- `DisplayName`
- `LastAccessDate` *([Datetime user last loaded a page; updated every 30 min at most](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294750/230261))*
- `WebsiteUrl`
- `Location`
- `AboutMe`
- `Views` *([Number of times the profile is viewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311938/what-is-views-of-users-in-the-database-schema-documentation))*
- `UpVotes` *([How many upvotes the user has cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260897/what-is-upvotes-of-users-in-database-schema-documentation))*
- `DownVotes`
- `ProfileImageUrl`
- `EmailHash` *(now always blank)*
- `AccountId`  *(User's Stack Exchange Network profile ID)*

---

### *Comments*

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `Score`
- `Text` *(Comment body)*
- `CreationDate`
- `UserDisplayName`
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(Optional. Absent if user has been deleted)*
- `ContentLicense`

---

### *Badges*

- `Id`
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `Name` *(Name of the badge)*
- `Date` (e.g. `2008-09-15T08:55:03.923`)
- `Class`
  <sub>1 = Gold

  2 = Silver

  3 = Bronze</sub>
- `TagBased` = *`True` if badge is for a tag, otherwise it is a named badge*

---

### CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes

- `Id`
- `IsUniversal`
- `InputTitle`
- `MarkdownInputGuidance` *shown while flagging/voting*
- `MarkdownPostOwnerGuidance` *shown when closed to OP*
- `MarkdownPublicGuidance` *shown when closed to priviledged users*
- `MarkdownConcensusDescription` (sic) *(nullable)* *shown above the public or post owner guidance*.
- `CreationDate`
- [`CreationModeratorId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `ApprovalDate`
- `ApprovalModeratorId`
- `DeactivationDate`
- [`DeactivationModeratorId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)

---

### PendingFlags

Despite the name, this table in fact contains close-related flags and votes.

- `Id`
- `FlagTypeId` *(listed in the [`FlagTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)*
  <sub>13 = canned flag for closure

  14 = vote to close

  15 = vote to reopen</sub>
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `CreationDate`
- `CloseReasonTypeId` *(listed in the [`CloseReasonTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)*
- `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId`, *if `CloseReasonTypeId = 102 (off-topic)` (listed in the [`CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)*
- [`DuplicateOfQuestionId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts), *if `CloseReasonTypeId` is 1 or 101 (old duplicate or current duplicate)*
- `BelongsOnBaseHostAddress`, *for votes to close and migrate*

---

### PostFeedback

Collects up and down votes from anonymous visitor and/or unregistered users. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194939/158100)

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `IsAnonymous`
- `VoteTypeId` *(listed in the [`VoteTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)*
  <sub>2 = UpMod

  3 = DownMod</sub>
- `CreationDate`

---

### *PostHistory*

*(Note that the history of deleted posts is scrubbed from this table in SEDE.)*

- `Id`
- `PostHistoryTypeId` *(listed in the [`PostHistoryTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)*
  <sub>1 = Initial Title - initial title *(questions only)*

  2 = Initial Body - initial post raw body text

  3 = Initial Tags - initial list of tags *(questions only)*

  4 = Edit Title - modified title *(questions only)*

  5 = Edit Body - modified post body (raw markdown)

  6 = Edit Tags - modified list of tags *(questions only)*

  7 = Rollback Title - reverted title  *(questions only)*

  8 = Rollback Body - reverted body (raw markdown)

  9 = Rollback Tags - reverted list of tags *(questions only)*

  10 = Post Closed - post voted to be closed

  11 = Post Reopened - post voted to be reopened

  12 = Post Deleted - post voted to be removed

  13 = Post Undeleted - post voted to be restored

  14 = Post Locked - post locked by moderator

  15 = Post Unlocked - post unlocked by moderator

  16 = Community Owned - post now community owned

  17 = Post Migrated - post migrated - *now replaced by 35/36 (away/here)*

  18 = Question Merged - question merged with deleted question

  19 = Question Protected - question was protected by a moderator.

  20 = Question Unprotected - question was unprotected by a moderator.

  21 = Post Disassociated - OwnerUserId removed from post by admin

  22 = Question Unmerged - answers/votes restored to previously merged question

  24 = Suggested Edit Applied

  25 = Post Tweeted

  31 = Comment discussion moved to chat

  33 = Post notice added - *`comment` contains foreign key to PostNotices*

  34 = Post notice removed - *`comment` contains foreign key to PostNotices*

  35 = Post migrated away - *replaces id 17*

  36 = Post migrated here - *replaces id 17*

  37 = Post merge source

  38 = Post merge destination

  50 = Bumped by Community User

  52 = Question became hot network question (main) / Hot Meta question (meta)

  53 = Question removed from hot network/meta questions by a moderator

  66 = Created from Ask Wizard</sub>

Additionally, in [older dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102644/230261) *(all guesses, all seem no longer present in the wild):*
<sub>23 = Unknown dev related event

26 = Vote nullification by dev *(ERM?)*

27 = Post unmigrated/hidden moderator migration?

28 = Unknown suggestion event

29 = Unknown moderator event *(possibly de-wikification?)*

30 = Unknown event *(too rare to guess)*</sub>

- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `RevisionGUID`: At times more than one type of history record can be recorded by a single action.  All of these will be grouped using the same RevisionGUID
- `CreationDate` (e.g. `2009-03-05T22:28:34.823`)
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `UserDisplayName`: populated if a user has been removed and no longer referenced by user Id
- `Comment`: This field will contain the comment made by the user who edited a post.

  - If PostHistoryTypeId = 10, this field contains the CloseReasonId of the close reason (listed in `CloseReasonTypes`):
    <sub>***Old close reasons:***

    1 = Exact Duplicate

    2 = Off-topic

    3 = Subjective and argumentative

    4 = Not a real question

    7 = Too localized

    10 = General reference

    20 = Noise or pointless (Meta sites only)

    ***Current close reasons:***

    101 = Duplicate

    102 = Off-topic

    103 = Unclear what you're asking

    104 = Too broad

    105 = Primarily opinion-based</sub>
  - If `PostHistoryTypeId in (33,34)` this field contains the `PostNoticeId` of the `PostNotice`
- `Text`: A raw version of the new value for a given revision
  <sub>- If `PostHistoryTypeId in (10,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,35)` this column will contain a JSON encoded string with all users who have voted for the `PostHistoryTypeId`</sub>
  <sub>- If it is a duplicate close vote, the JSON string will contain an array of original questions as `OriginalQuestionIds`</sub>
  <sub>- If `PostHistoryTypeId = 17` this column will contain migration details of either `from <url>` or `to <url>`</sub>
- `ContentLicense`

---

### *PostLinks*

- `Id` primary key
- `CreationDate` when the link was created
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) id of source post
- [`RelatedPostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) id of target/related post
- `LinkTypeId`  type of link
  <sub>1 = Linked (`PostId` contains a link to `RelatedPostId`)

  3 = Duplicate (`PostId` is a duplicate of `RelatedPostId`)</sub>

---

### PostNotices

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- [`PostNoticeTypeId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=postnoticetypes)
  <sub>1 = Citation needed

  2 = Current event

  3 = Insufficient explanation

  10 = Current answers are outdated

  11 = Draw attention

  12 = Improve details

  13 = Authoritative reference needed

  14 = Canonical answer required

  15 = Reward existing answer

  20 = Content dispute

  21 = Offtopic comments

  22 = Historical significance

  23 = Wiki Answer</sub>
- `CreationDate`
- `DeletionDate`
- `ExpiryDate`
- `Body`  *(when present contains the custom text shown with the notice)*
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- [`DeletionUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)

---

### PostNoticeTypes

- `Id`
- `ClassId`
  <sub>1 = Historical lock

  2 = Bounty

  4 = Moderator notice</sub>
- `Name`
- `Body`  *(contains the default notice text)*
- `IsHidden`
- `Predefined`
- `PostNoticeDurationId`
  <sub>-1 = No duration specified

  1 = 7 days (bounty)</sub>

---

### PostTags

- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- [`TagId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=tags)

---

### ReviewRejectionReasons

Canned rejection reasons for suggested edits. See [Show all review rejection reasons](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199800/show-all-review-rejection-reasons)

- `Id`
- `Name`
- `Description`
- `PostTypeId` (for reasons that apply to Wiki (5) or Excerpt (6) post types only, otherwise null)

---

### ReviewTaskResults

- `Id`
- [`ReviewTaskId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=reviewtasks)
- `ReviewTaskResultTypeId` (listed in [`ReviewTaskResultTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))
  <sub>1 = Skip

  2 = Approve (suggested edits)

  3 = Reject (suggested edits)

  4 = Delete (low quality)

  5 = Edit (first posts, late answers, low quality)

  6 = Close (close, low quality)

  7 = Looks OK (low quality)

  8 = Do Not Close (close)

  9 = Recommend Deletion (low quality answer)

  10 = Recommend Close (low quality question)

  11 = Other Action (first posts), previously "I'm Done"

  12 = Reopen (reopen)

  13 = Leave Closed (reopen)

  14 = Edit and Reopen (reopen)

  15 = Excellent (community evaluation)

  16 = Satisfactory (community evaluation)

  17 = Needs Improvement (community evaluation)

  18 = No Action Needed (first posts, late answers)</sub>
- `CreationDate` date only (`2018-07-31 00:00:00`); time data looks to be [purposefully removed to protect user privacy](/q/933)
- `RejectionReasonId` (for suggested edits; listed in `ReviewRejectionReasons`)
- `Comment`

---

### ReviewTasks

- `Id`
- `ReviewTaskTypeId` (listed in [`ReviewTaskTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))
  <sub>1 = Suggested Edit

  2 = Close Votes

  3 = Low Quality Posts

  4 = First Post

  5 = Late Answer

  6 = Reopen Vote

  7 = Community Evaluation

  8 = Link Validation

  9 = Flagged Posts

  10 = Triage

  11 = Helper

  12 = First Questions

  13 = First Answers</sub>
- `CreationDate` date only (`2018-07-31 00:00:00`)
- `DeletionDate` date only (`2018-07-31 00:00:00`)
- `ReviewTaskStateId` (listed in [`ReviewTaskStates`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199801/show-all-review-task-states))
  <sub>1 = Active

  2 = Completed

  3 = Invalidated</sub>
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- [`SuggestedEditId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=suggestededits) (for suggested edits, which have their own numbering for historical reasons)
- [`CompletedByReviewTaskId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=ReviewTaskResults)  id associated to the ReviewTaskResult that stores the outcome of a completed review.

---

### SuggestedEdits

If both approval and rejection date are null then this edit is still in review (and its corresponding entry in `ReviewTasks` will have an active state as well).

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `CreationDate`
- `ApprovalDate` - NULL if not approved (yet).
- `RejectionDate` - NULL if not rejected (yet).
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `Comment`
- `Text`
- `Title`
- `Tags`
- `RevisionGUID`

---

### SuggestedEditVotes

- `Id`
- [`SuggestedEditId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=suggestededits)
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `VoteTypeId` (listed in the [`VoteTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)
  <sub>2 = Approve (technically UpMod)

  3 = Reject (technically DownMod)</sub>
- `CreationDate`
- [`TargetUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)
- `TargetRepChange`

---

### *Tags*

- `Id`
- `TagName`
- `Count`
- [`ExcerptPostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)  *(nullable) Id of Post that holds the excerpt text of the tag*
- [`WikiPostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts) *(nullable) Id of Post that holds the wiki text of the tag*
- `IsModeratorOnly`
- `IsRequired`

---

### TagSynonyms

- `Id`
- [`SourceTagName`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=tags&pk=tagname)  *(nullable)*
- [`TargetTagName`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=tags&pk=tagname)  *(nullable)*
- `CreationDate`
- [`OwnerUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)   *(nullable)*
- `AutoRenameCount`
- `LastAutoRename` *(nullable)*
- `Score`
- [`ApprovedByUserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users)  *(nullable)*
- `ApprovalDate` *(nullable)*

---

### *Votes*

- `Id`
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=posts)
- `VoteTypeId` *(listed in the [`VoteTypes`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) table)*
  <sub>1 = AcceptedByOriginator

  2 = UpMod *([AKA upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536))*

  3 = DownMod *([AKA downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536))*

  4 = Offensive

  5 = Favorite *([AKA bookmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558); `UserId` will also be populated)*  *feature removed after October 2022 / replaced [by Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019)*

  6 = Close (effective 2013-06-25: Close votes are **only** stored in table: `PostHistory`)

  7 = Reopen

  8 = BountyStart *(`UserId` and `BountyAmount` will also be populated)*

  9 = BountyClose *(`BountyAmount` will also be populated)*

  10 = Deletion

  11 = Undeletion

  12 = Spam

  15 = ModeratorReview *(i.e., [a moderator looking at a flagged post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536))*

  16 = ApproveEditSuggestion</sub>
- [`UserId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607?table=users) *(present only if `VoteTypeId in (5,8)`; -1 if user is deleted)*
- `CreationDate` Date only (`2018-07-31 00:00:00` *[time data is purposefully removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/933/163250) to protect user privacy)*
- `BountyAmount` (present only if `VoteTypeId in (8,9)`)

---

### xxxTypes

*Not listed here:*

- `xxxTypes` tables which list (Id, Name) pairs for `Posts.PostTypeId`, `Votes.VoteTypeId`, etc. See [Show all types](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) for an up-to-date list of all types.

---

### All Tables/Columns/Type

Find the exact [T-SQL datatype](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and length/precision of each specific column in this query:

[List all Fields in all Tables on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835150/list-all-fields-in-all-tables-on-sede?/)

---

## TIMESTAMPS

All timestamps are [**`UTC`**](https://www.epochconverter.com/), default format: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (stored with milliseconds).

**Example of conversion** current time to `PST` (including [DST](https://www.google.com/search?q=dst)) using [`At Time Zone`](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql):

```
SELECT GetDate() At Time Zone 'UTC' At Time Zone 'Pacific Standard Time'
```

<sub>To **list time zones**: `SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info`</sub>

Comment: For PostNoticeTypes, there appears to be two `classId`s other than the mentioned 1, 2, & 4. [Stack Overflow additionally as 8 and 0](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1393012), it seems most (all?) other sites have just the 8. Is there an official name for this class of notices?

Comment: @zcoop98 I've run a check and [you're right, only 1 site has 0 as classid](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1400034). I checked but can't find info on what the name of those classid's is. Feel free to open a question to get that name. Here is the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278150 that announces the addition of those tables. Surprisingly enough I was the requestor to get those tables added in the first place.

Comment: Why is there UserName in Post and Comment? Is it to avoid a join? Are the username entries in posts and comments updated if user updates the username?

Comment: @chaosifier Username is populated when a User is deleted. So once the Userid or OwnerUserId would be set to null the Usename field gets populated with the last known name (although most of the time the username is reset to default first)

Comment: How can you tell if a vote is for a comment or for a post? It seems like the schema only handles votes for posts.

Comment: @AlexJ Comments only have upvotes and those are kept in the field ` Score` . There is no separate table for CommentVotes. So the votes(votetypeid in (2,3)) table has the rows for up and downvotes of posts alone.

Comment: @rene Interesting, what keeps a user from making multiple upvotes on a given comment? How is the vote on a comment related back to the user that makes it?

Comment: @AlexJ the schema of the production database is more extensive

Comment: I'm looking for `Users.Title`. Where is it?!

Comment: @BenyaminJafari see [How can I query users with a specific Job title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341120/how-can-i-query-users-with-a-specific-job-title)

Comment: What does AcceptedAnswerId mean? I wish there was documentation specifically telling about it.

Comment: @desert_ranger see [Which Stack Overflow table saves the data for accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257588/which-stack-overflow-table-saves-the-data-for-accepted-answers)

Comment: Is there an access to Twitter / Github usernames? I don't see such columns but it's a public information...

Comment: @IvanKleshnin please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335060/158100 tl;dr: they are not in the schema.

Answer (score 53):

The Schema Visualized
[image: SEDE ERD]
The Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) above was constructed using the data found in the *information_schema.columns* table. (Thank you to [ashleedawg](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1023678/1114977/all-tables-columns-data-typesincl-length-or-precision-in-sede) for paring the table down to its bare essentials).

All the table, column and key information were compiled into a SQL script using python3. The results were cross validated with the accepted answer above, and the few idiosyncratic foreign key formations left over were hardcoded in at the end.)

The ERD was then reverse engineered using *dbschema*.

Please find the script that wrote the SQL and other related files in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/leerssej/SEDESchema).

The interactive HTML version of the ERD is posted here:
https://sedeschema.github.io/

Comment: It could use a key. For example, what are the dashed lines for?

Comment: for further information about ERD key relationship representations (and the start of a path down into the UML structure and format hole) please see here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76532/how-to-represent-foreign-key-in-an-er-diagram

Comment: @leerssej It is not explained in the provided reference what the dashed/solid line styles stand for. At least I couldn't find this.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Please see the third sentence in the first response. Link here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/76547/109673

Comment: @leerssej Thanks, however the linked answer does not explicitly mention a line being solid or dashed: _"ER Diagrams were originally used only to represent the ER model. The ER model does not use foreign keys to represent relationships. It uses lines between boxes. The lines have some kind of indicator for cardinality at either end or both ends. Sometimes, a relationship will be indicated separately by a diamond."_ What is confusing to me is whether dashing conveys additional information to symbols at the ends of a line or not. ... [1/n]

Comment: You seem to imply that dashing is an indicator of cardinality and should be considered *together* with the end symbols. This agrees with [dbSchema documentation](https://dbschema.com/documentation/schema.html#fk), although it does not show exactly the same notation you used in the picture (you have "P", "Z", or "1" at the ends; the docs show Crow's foot and notches). ... [2/3]

Comment: On the other hand, [this](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/ERStudioDA/185/en/IE_%28Crow%27s_Feet%29_Notation) shows that dashed (non-solid) line indicates something on top of those symbols; something related to identifying or non-identifying relationships. This variety of notations and possibilities make the topic confusing for a non-expert, and it would be great to know at least something with certainty. [3/3]

Comment: @paperskilltrees Ah! Now I understand your question: what is the difference between the dashed lines and the solid lines? Thank you for the clarification!
Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697896/5088194 or this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/16676282