# Vote datetime in datadump - No time?

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, statistics, data-analysis

In the votes table, the field CreationDate in the votes table only contains the date, with all the times set to 12:00:00 AM.

For some purporses, this information is needed to determine if there are [issues regarding accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste) in particular, and perhaps other types of voting patterns.

- Is this how SO internally stores the data, and if so can this be changed so the time is also recorded?
- If this data is scrubbed during the dump (in order to prevent, for instance, matching up voting times with times people were seen on SO) can this be more finely grained so that some types of votes, such as `AcceptedByOriginator`, `Close`, `Reopen`, `Deletion`, `Undeletion` will have the actual vote times?

This can be useful for generating data that may show how changes to the system are likely to affect behavior, and to measure the effectiveness of new features/badges/etc.  The five vote types I've specified above don't require anonymity since we know who voted to accept, and who votes to close and open questions already.  However if it's still a risk, please at least let us see when answers are accepted, which has no risk of personally identifying information.

Similar to this question:

[Why is vote time missing in the SE data dump and SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/omission-of-vote-time-in-data-dump)

However, I'm asking that only a portion of the data be made available, data which is already public on the website, so there's no point in anonymizing it.  The above question was asking that all voting times be made available.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/omission-of-vote-time-in-data-dump

Comment: @Greg - While similar, this one is requesting only the data which does not require anonymization, rather than all the times for all the votes.

Comment: *starts singing* - Reputation wants to be *freeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee...!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you should know that all ...

- Close
- Reopen
- Deletion
- Undeletion

... votes are automatically aged away and hard deleted 4 days after they've been cast. So there's no actual permanent record of these votes being cast, unless the threshold is reached on the question.

So all you'd really be getting is the acceptance vote date and time.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Well, acceptance would still be nice for the reasons mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this information would be really useful - it would be great to see it for all types of votes (useful for things like seeing how many upvotes a post receives after its been marked as accepted) but in particular its good for the "special" vote types (closing, accepting answers etc...)