# Why are there only 4 days worth of close/reopen votes in the Data Explorer?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, data-explorer

As the title states - what's the deal?  Did close votes just start being added?  Are the ones that are there only there because of some transient experiment?

[Example Query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/3464/)

I'm pretty sure that a *few* more than 1806 close/reopen votes have been cast in Stack Overflow's history, and that at least some of those happened before May 28, 2010.  There only seems to be 4 days worth of results, from May 28 to May 31, and curiously they're all at midnight (or maybe the time of day isn't being stored).

Can anyone explain this to me?  Have I just misunderstood the schema perhaps?

Comment: Hmmm.. dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37524/request-for-data-dump-to-include-more-closed-question-info

Comment: I was thinking of the same question, @Jon, but it feels odd to call it duplicate. This is the weird kind of situation where a question is answered in the body of another question (which is unfortunately an unanswered question in itself). So they wouldn't attract the same answers. Not sure what protocol for this would be.

Comment: @Jon: Well, not a dupe, but I guess the answer might be that DE is like that because the dump itself is like that.  I'd really like an actual explanation, though...

Comment: @ccomet, @Aarobot: Check out this search: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[data-dump]+close

Comment: Also, this mostly answers your questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38451/vote-datetime-in-datadump-no-time/41728#41728

Comment: @Jon That last one hits it. Nicely found.

Comment: Crud.  Why on earth would they hard-delete the votes?  I think it's really important to be able to analyze that data in order to understand how the community moderation system actually works in practice on a larger scale.  I guess we'll never know.

Comment: The aging mechanism/numbers have changed since this question was posted. See [Jeff's post here](/a/97581/997587), [a reference to Jeff's post here](/a/120902/997587), and [a reference to the reference to Jeff's post here as an answer to an FAQ post](/a/204347/997587). See also [Shog9's answer to "How do close votes age away?"](/a/166124/997587).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38451/vote-datetime-in-datadump-no-time/41728#41728), close votes auto-decay and are hard-deleted after 4 days.

The close votes are also stripped of their time. This is part of the anonymization, and it is documented in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/omission-of-vote-time-in-data-dump), specifically by Jeff [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/omission-of-vote-time-in-data-dump/941#941).

Comment: This has changed since the answer was posted. See [Jeff's post here](/a/97581/997587), [a reference to Jeff's post here](/a/120902/997587), and [a reference to the reference to Jeff's post here as an answer to an FAQ post](/a/204347/997587). See also [Shog9's answer to "How do close votes age away?"](/a/166124/997587).