# Expose vote time data for accepts, bounty starts/awards, and edit approvals in the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

To preface, I'm not asking for vote time to be exposed for upvotes or downvotes. I'm aware that that's bad because it allows voting history to be reconstructed.

However, certain other types of votes already have their times publicly exposed elsewhere but not in the Data Explorer. In particular:

- The time of an accept (VoteTypeId = 1) can be seen at `/posts/<id>/timeline`.
- The time of a bounty start or a bounty award (8, 9) is visible at `/posts/<id>/revisions`.
- The time at which an edit is approved (16) is also visible at `/posts/<id>/revisions`.

It would be awesome if the times at which these types of votes were cast could be added to the `Votes` table. (By which I mean, instead of having `CreationDate` always be `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00`, have actual times for these types of votes.)

Motivation: mostly, I want to look at the duration of time between an answer being posted and it being accepted, and see how that correlates to other things about the question/answer. So I'm mostly interested in type 1 votes; the others I've included here just for completeness. Jeff mentions that adding accept times to the data dump would not be objectionable to him in [a post from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41728/224428), but it doesn't look like anything came of that.

Comment: Adding bookmarks to the list could be nice too; I don't see any immediate issues with de-anonymizing the timestamp for those either.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but addresses two of your requests.

The exact accept time can't be known.

For approved edits you can inspect the table `suggestededits`. The column `approvaldate` will hold the exact timestamp the suggestededit was approved.

For the exact timestamp on all edits on a post you can look at `posthistorytypeid` for the rows with `posthistorytypeid` values of 4, 5 or 6. (title, body and tag edits events), the creationdate will have the exact timestamp.

For bounties you can look at the creationdate en deletiondate of PostNotices. You need to join with PostNoticeTypes because the rows with classid = 2 indicate a bounty. This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/987004) produces that data:

```sql
select top 100 pn.id
          , pn.postid
          , pn.creationdate
          , pn.deletiondate
          , v.creationdate [vote date]
          , v.votetypeid   [vote type]
from postnotices pn
inner join votes v on v.postid = pn.postid 
inner join postnoticetypes pnt on pnt.id = pn.postnoticetypeid
                              and pnt.classid = 2 -- bounty
where (v.votetypeid  = 8 
and v.creationdate = convert(date, pn.creationdate))
or (v.votetypeid  = 9 
and v.creationdate = convert(date, pn.deletiondate))

order by pn.postid
```