# Does the public data dump contain user names or not?

Tags: support, data-dump, display-names

I'm not exactly feeling like [downloading 13.2 GB](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2141-jun-2013) to figure this out, but I'm a bit confused here: What does *anonymized* data dump mean? Does this mean the usernames are removed despite CC BY-SA license or what kind of anonymization is taking place here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data dump is basically identical to what's available in the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), except in XML and offline.

Things like specific voting data and the users' personal information are scrubbed out, but we of course respect our own content license and usernames and association between posts and their authors are both available as expected.

You can download a much smaller data dump of one of the closed sites to get a feel for it. For example, [Literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature).

Comment: That was quick, thanks! Ah, for more details on the dump's contents, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/146482). With personal information, I assume you refer to "Real Name" etc., i.e. everything that no one but mods (or even only devs) can see anyway, correct?

Answer (score 1):

So far I've found the following columns that show on the public dump that differ from the presumed original internal SE values:

- `Votes.UserId` is `NULL` for most vote types, including upvotes or downvotes. Or else we'd know who voted on posts.
- `Votes.CreationDate`: the time in hours and finer is truncated to 0: [Why is vote time missing in the SE data dump and SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/why-is-vote-time-missing-in-the-se-data-dump-and-sede)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/146482), the dump contains a `OwnerDisplayName` field, so that's not the anonymization taking place. But things that are also not available online, e.g. *who* voted how, are of course not included.

Comment: Did you intend to answer your own question in the first place, or just found the answer yourself so fast?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The latter. Otherwise I would have checked the "answer immediately" box.

Comment: Yeah, thought you might have missed that. :)