# Is it possible for users to view a post's up and down vote history?

Tags: support, questions, answers, voting, reputation-history

Is it possible to view a graph showing a post's up and down votes over time?

Not who voted for it, just "vote received at [timestamp]". I know if a user has enough rep they can see the total up and down votes their post has received so far, but I'm not aware of being able to see the history of votes on a post.

Comment: You can see a daily log of votes at the post's timeline (`/posts/[post ID]/timeline`).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I don't know why you didn't make that an answer as that was exactly what I was after! **Edit:** actually, it doesn't show all votes, but an aggregate, but it's close enough!

Comment: Well... it’s not quite what you want. It’s not time stamped per vote. It’s a daily digest of the score changing.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I was interpreting votes on answers as votes on the question. I was hoping for more granularity than a day.

Comment: If I remember correctly, not even mods see that. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, since it doesn't provide specific timestamps, I kept it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: You can also do that with the help of some JavaScript and the [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-timeline). However, there's no graph and things are more complicated with this method.

Answer (score 6):

You want a graph, [you get a graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1172729/score-graph?PostId=1#graph). It's holiday season after all:

[image]

As you noticed, [vote timestamps are missing time information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/933/295232), and data may be (up to) 7 days old since SEDE is refreshed once a week on Sunday morning. Notice the use of [parameters](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/query-parameters) to reuse the query for multiple posts. Editing them repeatedly gets rather tedious :)

Comment: I have no idea how you got "Graph" to magically come up but it's very cool!

Comment: @CoolFool Graphs are generated automatically depending on the output of a query: https://data.stackexchange.com/help#graphing

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool called [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that allows users to perform queries on Stack Exchange's databases. Although it's not graphical, the raw data can be used to create a graph.

For instance, to view the voting history of the first ever Meta Stack Exchange question go to https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/new and run the below query:

```
SELECT v.Id
      ,v.PostId
      ,vt.Name as VoteType
      ,v.UserId
      ,v.CreationDate
      ,v.BountyAmount
FROM Votes v
JOIN VoteTypes vt
  ON vt.id = v.VoteTypeId
WHERE PostId = 1
ORDER BY CreationDate
```

Output:

```
Id | PostId | VoteType | UserId | CreationDate        | BountyAmount
---+--------+----------+--------+---------------------+-------------
 2 |      1 | UpMod    |        | 2009-06-28 00:00:00 |
 4 |      1 | UpMod    |        | 2009-06-28 00:00:00 |
 5 |      1 | UpMod    |        | 2009-06-28 00:00:00 |
 7 |      1 | UpMod    |        | 2009-06-28 00:00:00 |
 8 |      1 | Favorite |  84671 | 2009-06-28 00:00:00 |
.
.
.
```

The timestamps are all at midnight of that day, and the data is not available until about 7 days have passed. For the votes on this question, replace `WHERE PostId = 1` with `WHERE PostId = 341195`.