# Is there any way to view an answer's score over time?

Tags: support, data-explorer, score

I'd like to see the time-graph of how many points an answer (or a question, I guess?) had.

Can I get at that data (even in a raw form, to shove into Excel!)

Comment: [My answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341202/295232) contains a query which does graphs.

Comment: Ah, I used all the wrong keywords, huh :) Thanks @Glorfindel